Failed to resolve host network app id to config: bundleID: com.apple.WebKit.Networking
I got this message in Xcode when I start the emulator:
Failed to resolve host network app id to config: bundleID: com.apple.WebKit.Networking

What is this message about and how should I fix it ?
It looks like it's what makes requests to Firebase to fail.
here is a screenshot


Solved here with the version 11.25.0
npm i react-native-webview@11.25.0


But I'm not using react native at all

There's a lot of us experimenting trouble with the latest react native for the initial loading of react native webview. I had the same error code for the webview embedded in react native youtube iframe. Just actualising the component with a key props solved it.
Here's my code (using webview 13.12.4) :
const [webviewKey, setWebviewKey]=useState(1)

   useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === "ios"){
            setTimeout(()=>setWebviewKey(key=>key+1), 50)
        }
    }, [])

   <YoutubePlayer
          height={RPW(56)}
          videoId={article.video_id}

          webViewProps={{
          key : webviewKey,
          }}
   />


For more details : https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/3616
